# my PHP cannot post data to my url

Tags: php, ajax, post

I try searching about this but I just can't find any that can solve my problem. I want to produce a url like to this to send request to my webservice:

`http://localhost/jQueryStudy/RamagalHTML/processjson3.php?
path=update%2FtallyHdr&json=
{"SessionID":"hHuCG3Jt1um5gV7kE320Bw7EjG97I4qZ","operation":"add",
"transaction_date":"2011-7-29","supplier_id":"10000000108","wood_specie_id":"1",
"lines":[{"plank_number":"7","thickness":"5","width":"8","length_t":"8","quantity":"1","board_foot":"26.67","wood_classification_id":"1","price":"15"}],"scaled_by":"WER","tallied_by":"WE","checked_by":"WE","total_bdft":"580.00","final":"N"}`

Here's my current javascript code i have right now:

```
var dataJSON = {
    "SessionID": $.cookie("SessionID"),
    "operation": "add",       
    "transaction_date":$('#tallyDate').val(),
    "supplier_id":$('#supplierInput').attr("name"),
    "wood_specie_id":$('#woodSpecie').attr("name"),   
    "lines":plank_data,
    "scaled_by":$('#tallyScaled').val().toUpperCase(),
    "tallied_by":$('#tallyTallied').val().toUpperCase(),
    "checked_by":$('#tallyChecked').val().toUpperCase(),
    "total_bdft":$('#tallyTotal').val(),
    "final":"N"
  }; 
  alert('this is the datajson from add :   '  + JSON.stringify(dataJSON));

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: dataJSON,
    url: 'processjson2.php?path=update/tallyHdr',
    dataType: primeSettings.ajaxDataType,
    success: function(data) {
      if ('error' in data)
      {
        showMessage('ERROR: ' + data["error"]["msg"]);
      }
      else{
        $('#tblTallyHdr').trigger('reloadGrid'); 
      }
    }
  });
```

My .php code is this:

```
<?php
   $data_url = http_build_query (array('json' => $_REQUEST["json"]));
   $data_len = strlen ($data_url); 

echo file_get_contents("http://localhost:8001/" . $_REQUEST["path"], false, stream_context_create(
    array (
        'http' => array(
            'method'=>'POST',
            'header' => "Connection: close\r\nContent-Length: $data_len\r\n",
            'content'=>$data_url
        )
    )
));
```

Evrytime I run my program, the url is only this `http://localhost/jQueryStudy/RamagalHTML/processjson2.php?path=update/tallyHdr`, the data was not posted which makes my request not executed. Please help me on this. I don't know how to fix my php.

Comment: `POST` information is not sent in the URL in the same manner as `GET`. When you say you can't see it in the URL, how are you observing it?

Comment: In firebug, i can see it in my console that my url lacks the data I need. And I also do tracing in my delphi program where i write mmy webservce code. My json request is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're wanting all your data to be sent as part of the URL then you should use GET, not POST.

It's therefore possible to do away with the data property and append everything to the request URL:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'processjson2.php?path=update/tallyHdr&json='+dataJSON,
    dataType: primeSettings.ajaxDataType,
    success: function(data) {
      if ('error' in data)
      {
        showMessage('ERROR: ' + data["error"]["msg"]);
      }
      else{
        $('#tblTallyHdr').trigger('reloadGrid'); 
      }
    }
  });
```

If you must use POST, then you just need to provide a variable name to go with your json:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: "json="+dataJSON,
    url: 'processjson2.php?path=update/tallyHdr',
    dataType: primeSettings.ajaxDataType,
    success: function(data) {
      if ('error' in data)
      {
        showMessage('ERROR: ' + data["error"]["msg"]);
      }
      else{
        $('#tblTallyHdr').trigger('reloadGrid'); 
      }
    }
  });
```

For more info, see the examples towards the end of the page: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: That was my code before but since there's a possibility that I will be sending many request data to my webservice, using `get` method will not execute it because of query string limit. That why I have no other choice but to use `POST` method.

Comment: You should be able to see the POST data using Firebug's Net tab.  Can you confirm that there is no POST data being sent?

Comment: shanethehat, it's working now. I just change my data into this `data: $.param({json:(JSON.stringify(dataJSON))}),`. Thanks for helping me out and for giving me a tip on providing a variable name for my json. WWAAHHHH, i am so happy since I already carrying this problem for two days now...